# How can I position these divs inside a td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I'm having a problem with elements positioning. What I want is something like this:
[image]

with a div with some divs inside at the top of the td, and a div at the bottom of the td. With my code, it works on Chrome, IE11 and Opera, but not in Firefox nor IE9. In those browsers it isn't well displayed:
[image]

As you can see, events from 7th are overlapping 14th td. It should be displayed as 13th for example. At first, I thought it was a float bug of Firefox, but now I think it's not.

```css
.td {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.top-div {
  height: 85%;
}

.divs-inside-top-div {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.bottom-div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FE9A2E;
}
```

```html
<td>
    <div class="top-div">
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div"></div>
</td>
```

I tried to put clear:both in all the elements, but to no effect.

Could tell me anybody how to display correctly in Firefox?

EDIT:

This is how i can see it in chrome for example:

[image]

Comment: If you put `overflow: hidden` in `td` is that the layout you want? And why would you think you have a `float` bug if you're not using `float`?

Comment: Why would you need to put `div` into a `td`?

Comment: @Klors, I would like to show all the content. As I said, In chrome, opera or ie11 looks ok. I'll add a image in that browsers.

Comment: @Curt because I have to add dynamically elements to the td's, and I thought that this was the best way... Is there another one better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this would give you what you're trying to achieve?

The `min-height`s are because they need some content to display otherwise. If you would you need space between the bottom and the top div then you'll have to give the td a height and position bottom-div absolutely.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  width: 100px;
}

.top-div {
}

.divs-inside-top-div {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
.divs-inside-top-div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.divs-inside-top-div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.divs-inside-top-div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #999999;
}

.bottom-div {
  background-color: #FE9A2E;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="top-div">
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
        <div class="divs-inside-top-div"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-div"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not neccesary to have space between top and bottom div, only if there's no content enough to fill all the td. The problem comes when there are various events and in total, their height is higher than td's height.

Comment: @etriix What would you do in that situation, if you don't want to hide the overflow? Would you have the row height increase?

Comment: resize td height, I just want to show them like the las image I uploaded

Comment: @etriix Could you not just have 2 rows per "row", one for the upper set of items that changes and one for the bottom? That way the upper one can align to the top and expand as needed, whereas the lower row can be a fixed size and will always be at the bottom?

Comment: yes... it could work well in that way. I'll make the changes later and test it. Thank you!